# How to assign and read values of public members of singleton class

Tags: c++, static, singleton

I have a class accessed as singleton with **public** members:

```
class MySingleton{
public:
    static MySingleton& Instance();
    int x;
...
}
```

the class is accessed as following:

```
MySingleton& MySingleton::Instance(){
        static MySingleton instance;
        return instance;
}
```

When i try to get the value of x i don't get the value i assigned before. i checked it with prints.

What is the proper way to change/get the value of x? should i use setters/getters? or can i do it directly in assignment?

Thank you all

Edit:
I have a single write to `x` as follows:

```
MySingleton::Instance().x = 2;
```

I get inconsistent values when i try to get `x` by accessing from different classes (single thread):

```
int z = MySingleton::Instance().x;
```

Comment: What it is printing?

Comment: Make a [mcve]. I can't reproduce the problem: https://godbolt.org/z/mZfkCq